# Why is 1<<3 + 1<<4 = 256?

Tags: python, binary, bit-manipulation, bit, boolean-algebra

I thought it would be equal to 1<<7 == 128, but why is it equal to 1<<8 == 256?
Could u please explain the algebra of x<<y + x<<z operations?

[python interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqrXf.png)

Comment: `(1 << (3 + 1)) << 4 == (1 << 4) << 4 == 16 << 4 == 256`

Comment: [python.org operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the python order of operations, where addition is evaluated before the left shift operator. The expression is equivalent to

```
(1<<(3+1))<<4
```